# D365 Web API / OData - Error while filtering relationship by "CascadeConfiguration" enum value

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to retrieve all one-to-many relationships of an entity where the `Delete` value of the `CascadeConfiguration` property is equal to `Cascade`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-metadata-web-api?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#use-enum-types-in-filter-operations), I'm using the following request (api version 9.0):

```
[organization url]/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OneToManyRelationshipMetadata/?$filter=ReferencedEntity eq 'contact' and CascadeConfiguration/Delete eq Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.CascadeType'Cascade'
```

or the equivalent

```
[organization url]/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')/OneToManyRelationships/?$filter=CascadeConfiguration/Delete eq Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.CascadeType'Cascade'
```

Both return the error message:
`Condition specified on property CascadeConfiguration of type RelationshipMetadataBase is invalid`.

The syntax is correct and there is no typo, because if I try changing other part of the url (eg. `CascadeConfiguration/WrongValue` or `Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.CascadeType'WrongType'`), I'm getting another error message.

I'm pretty sure the problem occurs because the [`RelationshipMetadataBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/relationshipmetadatabase?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) doesn't have a `CascadeConfiguration` property. The cast to a one-to-many relationship, which does [possess it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/onetomanyrelationshipmetadata?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9), is supposed to make it work.
If I use the filter clause `$filter=IsCustomizable/Value eq false`, the correct response is returned, because `IsCustomizable` is a property of `RelationshipMetadataBase`. This seems to confirm the previous point.

I am missing something?

Comment: Delete and Post commands you cannot try in the browser. Instead you have to try in code behind something like Rest call or XRM.Page.WebaPI call . Please refere here https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/muhsudcrmblog/posts/delete-record-using-web-api

Comment: It's not a post or delete, I'm retrieving metadata. It's working fine in the browser if I remove the `$filter` clause.

Comment: You can always create support ticket. we have had a few issued with complex webapi queries.